Applying Derivative Formula for $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\tan x}$
Using the identity, $\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, I used the derivative formula for limits. This is done as followed:
\begin{align}
\bigg(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\bigg)^{'}
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{\cos (x+h)}{\sin (x+h)}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos (x+h) \sin x - \cos x \sin (x+h)}{\sin (x+h) \sin x (h)} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos(x+h)\sin x - \cos x \sin(x+h) + \cos x \sin x - \cos x \sin x}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{\sin(x+h) \sin x} \frac{\cos(x+h) - \cos x}{h} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin(x+h) \sin x } \frac{\sin (x+h) - \sin x}{h} \\
&= \frac{\sin x}{\sin^2 x} \cos'(x) - \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x} \sin 'x \\
&= -1-\cot^2x
\end{align}
What went wrong with the working? This is wrong because I checked it on Wolfram Alpha.

You got the derivative correct. Your wolfram alpha check was incorrect.  Cf. this or this

In other words, leave out the letter $y$, and then wolfram alpha will say True

To answer the OP's question more directly:
Your entry on Wolfram Alpha was interpreted as a differential equation. You'll run into those later, probably; for now, just accept it as Wolfram misinterpreting your meaning.

Edit: The core reason for the interpretation was the use of $dy/dx$ as opposed to $d/dx$. The use of the $y$ signifies "there is an unknown function $y$ involved", whereas $d/dx$ is naturally interpreted as the derivative operation. Leaving that $y$ out, Wolfram Alpha rightfully returns "true", though I maintain that it can often be better to use the approach below sometimes (since it can sometimes make sources of error clear).

If you wish to check if an equality holds - for instance, does $\sin x = \cos x$, or does $f(x) = g(x)$ more generally - you should try an entry of the type $f(x) - g(x)$ and see if Wolfram Alpha outputs zero. However, it can be somewhat finicky sometimes, so sometimes it's just best to throw in each half of the equality individually and see if they simplify.

Example: Pythagorean identity
Example: Little Gauss
Non-Example: Square roots don't distribute
Non-Example: Freshman's Dream

This approach does struggle with derivatives though, so sticking to your formatting scheme:

Example: Power rule
Example: Lazily-handled fourth derivative of sine
Non-Example: A trig limit
Example where it doesn't give true/false, but is clearly still false


Another possible approach to compare with (based on the quotient rule):
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)' & = \frac{\cos'(x)\sin(x) - \cos(x)\sin'(x)}{\sin^{2}(x)}\\
& = -\frac{\sin^{2}(x) + \cos^{2}(x)}{\sin^{2}(x)}\\
& = -\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(x)}\\\\
& = -\csc^{2}(x)\\\\
& = -(1 + \cot^{2}(x))
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

If you wanted, the chain rule also works, assuming $\tan'(x) = \sec^2(x)$ is known:
$$\begin{align*}
\cot'(x)
&= \frac{d}{dx} \tan(x)^{-1} \
&= -\tan(x)^{-2} \sec^2(x)\
&= -\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} \frac{1}{\cos ^2 x} \
&= - \frac{1}{\sin^2 x} \
&= -\csc^2 x
\end{align*}$$

@PrincessEev Indeed :-)
